# Modify wpa_supplicant.conf with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to modify the file wpa_supplicant.conf via python. Therefore I wrote this script

```
def command_add_wifi(json):
  print("-> Adding wifi")
  
  # Read file WPA suppliant
  networks = []
  with open("wpa_supplicant.conf", "r") as f:
    in_lines = f.readlines()  

  # Discover networks
  out_lines = []
  networks = []
  country = ""
  i = 0
  isInside = False
  for line in in_lines:
    if "network={" == line.strip().replace(" ", ""):
      networks.append({})
      isInside = True
    elif "}" == line.strip().replace(" ", ""):
      i += 1
      isInside = False
    elif isInside:      
      key_value = line.strip().split("=")
      networks[i][key_value[0]] = key_value[1]
    else:
      out_lines.append(line)

  # Update password or add new
  isFound = False
  for network in networks:
    if network["ssid"] == f"\"{json['ssid']}\"":
      network["psk"] = f"\"{json['psk']}\""
      network["key_mgmt"] = f"\"{json['key_mgmt']}\""
      isFound = True
      break
    elif network["ssid"] != f"\"{json['ssid']}\"":
      network["ssid"] = f"\"{json['ssid']}\""
      network["psk"] = f"\"{json['psk']}\""
      network["key_mgmt"] = f"\"{json['key_mgmt']}\""
      isFound = True
      break;
  if not isFound:
     networks.append({
     'ssid': f"\"{json['ssid']}\"",
     'psk': f"\"{json['psk']}\"",
     'key_mgmt': "WPA-PSK"
     })

  # Generate new WPA Supplicant
  for network in networks:
    out_lines.append("network={\n")
    for key, value in network.items():
      out_lines.append(f"    {key}={value}\n")      
    out_lines.append("}\n\n")

  # Write to WPA Supplicant
  with open('wpa_supplicant.conf', 'w') as f:
    for line in out_lines:
      f.write(line)

  print("-> Wifi added !")
  
  
  
command_add_wifi({"ssid": "wiefaaeir_nraume", "psk": "fpassword", "key_mgmt": "key_mgmt"})
```

But I can't modify the country code. And I don't see the wood in front of the tree. How can i modify/read the parameter country as well?

This is the file

```
 # WiFi configuration generated by openHABian
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
# Network configuration was created by wpa_passphrase to ensure correct handling of special characters

network={
    ssid="wiefaaeir_nraume"
    psk="fpassword"
    key_mgmt="key_mgmt"
}
```

The script is working so far but I can not modify the country code.

Comment: Which part of your script did you expect to do anything with the country code?

Comment: As someone who's been doing devop for literally decades now -- I do not recommend writing code to modify configuration files in place. It's far more supportable to instead build templates to construct those files from data in a form chosen to be easy to work with. (Something like: JSON -> template engine -> config files)

Comment: (for doing this for a whole Linux distribution, see NixOS, where `configuration.nix` is used to programmatically generate every other config file in the system, and is in a powerful enough programming language that whatever domain logic one needs can be done there).

Comment: Just after the the comment "# Discover networks". It should be a new variable with country and there the DE should be saved

Comment: ...needing to parse arbitrary config file formats makes your code fragile -- any feature you don't currently support means a possible parse failure or incorrect parse; and even worse are cases where your generation code doesn't round-trip to its inputs when it's fed back through your parser. Going down that road is setting you up for a mountain of technical debt.

Comment: I'd suggest reformulating your question. As stated, the title is not a question at all. It would also be good to edit your code example. While showing the code you are having problems with is good, showing all of your code is not. Try to find the smallest amount of code that should work, but doesn't. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask